# correct terminology for "dead-end game"

Tags: algorithms, terminology, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Apologies if this question has an obvious answer!  My research is in pure math, but I've started to think about some applied problems that are similar to [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073327PM4) game.  The player arranges numbers 1-19 in a hexagon so that the numbers in each row add up to 38.  The game has been written about [here](https://chrisuehlinger.com/aristotle-puzzle/) and [here](http://hwiechers.blogspot.com/2013/03/solving-artitotles-number-puzzle.html).  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_hexagon) is the Wikipedia page for magic hexagons, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) is the Wikipedia page for magic squares.

Just like filling in a magic square, filling in a magic hexagon could be viewed as a "dead-end game:" By the time the player puts down, say, 5 pieces, they could have already lost the game --- but not realizing this, the player might continue to place more pieces on the board without seeing the futility of doing so, until they are stuck with the final pieces that they cannot place.  The player could waste a lot of time pursuing a solution after the placed pieces have rendered a solution impossible.  There must be an official name for this type of game, rather than "dead-end game."  Could anyone tell me the correct terminology?

Another "dead-end game:"  Biking around your neighborhood, trying not to wind up in a cul-de-sac (a literal dead-end), but not realizing that you've turned into a cul-de-sac until you reach the final houses on that street.

I've seen questions and answers on this site about algorithms for filling in magic squares.  **My question is not about solution methods, just about the terminology for games in which a player could waste time pursuing what is already a dead-end path.**  I'm sure this is a very common and well-studied type of game --- just need the terminology so I can learn more about it!  (Feel free to add or remove tags as appropriate.)

Comment: This experience is common to many people when playing Monopoly.

Comment: I don't know of any standard terminology for the property you are interested in. What you call "dead-end paths" are commonly called "blind alleys". You seem to be interested in games where there are blind alleys which aren't immediately blocked.

Comment: ["no-win"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-win_situation) ?

Comment: Thank you @RobArthan, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Just a side comment: perhaps confusingly, "dead end" has an unrelated meaning in Combinatorial Game Theory, as used in the paper [Dead Ends in Misere Play: The Misere Monoid of Canonical Numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6435)

Comment: Thank you @MarkS.!